# Running Total takes takes next record also while display

Tags: c#, vb.net, crystal-reports

I have to create CR for daybook with opening and closing balance. I am passing opening balance for startdate through parameters using SQL.Based on that opening balance i have to display opening balance, daybook entries and closing balance for each date(till enddate).

I'm using following formulas :

For Opening balance i used,

```
local bal as Number bal = {?openingbalance}
 if DateDiff ("d",CDate({DataTable0.date}) ,{?startdate} ) = 0 
then 
formula = {?openingbalance} 
else 
bal = {?openingbalance} + {#RTotal1}-{#RTotal2} 
formula = bal 
end if
```

and for closing balance i used

```
local bal as Number bal = {?openingbalance} + {#RTotal1}-{#RTotal2} 
formula = bal
```

By using this formulas, I can produce opening balance and closing balance correctly. But My Problem is last date closing balance displays in current date opening balance with adding of current date first entry.

Daybook Report
[image: Daybook Report]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you show us some code you tried.

Comment: Hi Maverick, For Opening balance i used,local bal as Number
bal = {?openingbalance}
if DateDiff ("d",CDate({DataTable0.date}) ,{?startdate} ) = 0 then
formula = {?openingbalance}
else
bal = {?openingbalance} + {#RTotal1}-{#RTotal2}
formula = bal
end if   and for closing balance i used    local bal as Number
bal = {?openingbalance} + {#RTotal1}-{#RTotal2}
formula = bal

Comment: @Priyas if you are adding code then edit question instead of writing comment.. for now I have added your code in question next time please edit question

Answer (score 0):

Looks like problem is with either `{DataTable0.date}` or `{?startdate}` as this difference is always not `0` hence opening balance part is going to else part every time and you are getting closing balance added for opening balance.

I doubt how you got first collection record in report... Check the values and try again.

If you are unable to check `{DataTable0.date}` then take care you always provide todays date in startdate paramter and change value like below in crystal report.

```
local bal as Number bal = {?openingbalance}
 if {?startdate}  = currentdate 
then 
formula = {?openingbalance} 
else 
bal = {?openingbalance} + {#RTotal1}-{#RTotal2} 
formula = bal 
end if
```

Let me know incase any issue in this part